# Is any other way to read message from webmail on cpanel using PHP with out using IMAP function

Tags: php, imap, fopen, pop3, webmail

I'm integrating PHP webmail read functionality in php. I already tried using IMAP functions. But it could not connect.So I just ask you is there any possibility to get messages from webamil with out using IMAP function.

Below is my IMAP Code. Can you check the code also give me suggestions for why doesn't work. I'm looking forward for your valuable reply.

```
$emailAddress = 'info@example.com'; // Full email address
$emailPassword = 'xxxxxxxx';        // Email password
$domainURL = 'example.com';         // Your websites domain
$useHTTPS = false;                      

/* BEGIN MESSAGE COUNT CODE */

$inbox = imap_open('{'.$domainURL.':143/notls}INBOX',$emailAddress,$emailPassword) or die('Cannot connect to domain:' . imap_last_error());
$oResult = imap_search($inbox, 'UNSEEN');

if(empty($oResult))
    $nMsgCount = 0;
else
    $nMsgCount = count($oResult);

imap_close($inbox);

echo('<p>You have '.$nMsgCount.' unread messages.</p>');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide the errors you get.  It may simply be a firewall issue, you may not be running an IMAP server on port 143, ....

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get inbox messages from CPanel Webmail using PHP IMAP functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617992/how-to-get-inbox-messages-from-cpanel-webmail-using-php-imap-functions)

Comment: This is also pretty much an exact duplicate of your other question.

Comment: @Max i found this error occur Cannot connect to domain:Can't connect to example.com,143: Unknown error (10013)
Notice: Unknown: Can't connect to example.com,143: Unknown error (10013) (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Have you actually checked that an IMAP server is running? And if it is, if it's running on that port?